# selecting a subset of a list of functions based off of the type of their arguments in scala

Tags: scala, shapeless

This is the code in question. Something of a description/explination is included below

```
object Functions {
  import scala.reflect.Manifest
  private var functions: List[(Manifest[_],Any,String)] = List()
  def add[T](desc: String,func: T)(implicit m: Manifest[T]) {
    functions ::= (m,func,desc)
  }

  def get[T]()(implicit m : Manifest[T]): List[(T,String)] = {
    functions flatMap {
      case (t,f,s) => if (t <:< m) Some(f.asInstanceOf[T],s) else None
    }
  }

  def getInputs[T]()(implicit m : Manifest[T]): List[(T => Any,String)] = {
  functions flatMap {
    case (t,f,s) => if (t <:< (T => Any)) Some(f.asInstanceOf[T => Any],s) else None
    }
  }
```

Basically my goal is to have a list of functions, with their types (input and output) perserved and the ability to search for specific functions based off of what they take as input and what they take as output. I am starting to believe that this is not possible in scala without some sort of a monkey patch, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: ``func: T`` is not a function, it is just a value named ``func`` which is of type ``T``. You probably want to make that ``func: T => T``.

Comment: You seem to be talking about the add[T] function. That one works as I would like it to.

Comment: What exactly is the question? This code works as it is, right?

Comment: No it does not even compile. I am going to try to use the shapeless library to get it to work.

Comment: @placeybordeaux I tested it... it works if you just change `t <:< (T => Any)` to `t <:< manifest[T => Any]`. http://ideone.com/Z4PjM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do what you want with [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless)'s `HLists`,

Sample REPL session,

```
scala> import shapeless._
import shapeless._

scala> val f1 : String => Int = _.length
f1: String => Int = <function1>

scala> val f2 : Boolean => Boolean = !_
f2: Boolean => Boolean = <function1>

scala> val f3 : Int => String = "("+_+")"
f3: Int => String = <function1>

scala> val fs = f1 :: f2 :: f3 :: HNil
fs: (String => Int) :: (Boolean => Boolean) :: (Int => String) :: HNil =
  <function1> :: <function1> :: <function1> :: HNil

scala> val args = "foo" :: true :: 23 :: HNil
args: String :: Boolean :: Int :: HNil = foo :: true :: 23 :: HNil

scala> fs zipApply args
res0: Int :: Boolean :: String :: HNil = 3 :: false :: (23) :: HNil
```

Note that the individual types of the functions are preserved in the `HList` `fs`, that the individual types of the argument values are preserved in `args`, and that the types of the elements of the result of the `zipApply` are determined appropriately by the types of the corresponding function and argument.

Comment: But can I search the list of functions based off of not their entire type, but for instance only their input types or output types?

Comment: Yes, `HLists` support selection of an element by (some function of their) type.

Comment: I didn't know this lib, it's very interesting !